# sklearn-weka-plugin return JavaException

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn, wrapper, weka

I am using the sklearn-weka-plugin and want to run the JRip classifier. When I try to run it with the python-weka-wrapper:

```
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.classifiers import Classifier

jvm.start()

jrip = Classifier("weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")

jvm.stop()
```

everything works fine, but if I try to do the same with the sklearn-weka-plugin:

```
import sklweka.jvm as jvm
from sklweka.classifiers import WekaEstimator

jvm.start()

jrip = WekaEstimator("weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")

jvm.stop()
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failed to get class weka.classifiers.rules.JRip
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka.classifiers.rules.JRip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sklearn_weka_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    jrip = WekaEstimator("weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklweka/classifiers.py", line 45, in __init__
    if not is_instance_of(_jobject, "weka.classifiers.Classifier"):
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weka/core/classes.py", line 285, in is_instance_of
    if is_array(obj):
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/weka/core/classes.py", line 309, in is_array
    cls = javabridge.call(obj, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;")
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/javabridge/jutil.py", line 888, in call
    fn = make_call(o, method_name, sig)
  File "/home/andreas/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/javabridge/jutil.py", line 846, in make_call
    raise JavaException(jexception)
javabridge.jutil.JavaException: weka.classifiers.rules.JRip
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, you should use `classname=` as all parameters of these classes are optional. The difference is that the first parameter of `Classifier` is `classname` and for `WekaEstimator` it is the JavaBridge object. That is why it works in the first case, but fails with an Exception in the second case.

Your code should look like this:

```py
import weka.core.jvm as jvm
from weka.classifiers import Classifier

jvm.start()

jrip = Classifier(classname="weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")

jvm.stop()
```

And:

```py
import sklweka.jvm as jvm
from sklweka.classifiers import WekaEstimator

jvm.start()

jrip = WekaEstimator(classname="weka.classifiers.rules.JRip")

jvm.stop()
```